# Liaise with s and e in French?

Tags: liaisons

Allez-vous essayer le vin?

Are you going to try the wine?

Should I pronunce it as "Allez-vousessayer le vin?"? Liaising with the s and e?
Is that common in French?

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question mais « Essayer un vin » n'a pas vraiment de sens. On peut éventuellement le goûter. La phrase aurait plus de sens avec un vêtement : « Allez-vous essayer le pantalon ? »

Comment: I deleted my answer because I found an online site saying "Après un pronom sujet inversé, la liaison est interdite" https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-87708.php, but I studied French and would pronounce it "zessayer"

Comment: If you are asking if this liaison is common, the answer is simple: it is not. French speakers do not make liaisons between a non-pronominal subjet and the following verb (some might exceptionally while reading from prepared notes) and it is the same with inverted subjects even pronominal ones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The s and the e shouldn’t be bound because of the « inversion sujet verbe » (allez-vous). Although, in French, we don’t try(essayer) aliments we taste(goûter) them.  **Allez-vous goûter le vin ?**

Comment: Pourquoi mon commentaire a-t-il été censuré ? En quoi enfreignait-il les règles ?